# TypeScript: Expecting type errors in this example. and not getting them. Am I missing something? Or just losing it?? :)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, types, typescript-generics

Not *that* new to TypeScript, but maybe new enough? And I'm puzzled here.. I was expecting some compiler errors and not getting them. Am I missing something?

(Better/runnable example is here on TS Playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsAPAFQHxQLxQDeAUFGVACYCGwVAXFQiADTEC+A3McaJFAKIA3CEgByVALYQAzvigAiAEYQAZnABOEAMpVh8qAB8FVFcnU69hhcrWaAIhAA2EZPqPyTZh89dduvaCERYAAJRgpndSxcAgAKAGNEZDQ6eCRUDBxmKAQMuliASjxsQjYi7AAFdTgJAEtpCHRGEGw-AIEkWtAAWTgKJ2i5EnIoOEUG9WF8iGExSQg6ILmpaWyAC3DIxdnQzYgonHLBOFqKLjZ-cGgAeQRHWtytNbgwMAeAcxgqdWB8YfIANoAawgIDoUGkwHUHwAugwmOxuMREghIVAJH0nItOj1MY50Ld7o9nq8Pl8fjEiKRyGMJlMoLEZsFxFJtsz5tJylTqWQLpxuBj+o4AHS0-bCWIAchsGm0uggkuyVGkIAQ8QZ5RI7AK3CAA) )

```
type Context<T> = {
    data:any,
};

type EventNames = "beforeSave" | "afterSave" | "beforeDelete" | "afterDelete";


type EventHandler<T> = (context:Context<T>, next:()=>{})=>Promise<any>;

type EntityModel<T> = {
    observe:(eventName:EventNames, handler:EventHandler<T>)=>void;
}

type OnlineShoppingCart ={
    [key: string]:any
}


const model:EntityModel<OnlineShoppingCart> = {
    observe: (eventName:EventNames)=> { 
// why am I not getting a compiler error here? 
// observe is not properly implemented!

    }
};

model.observe('beforeSave', async ()=>{
// why am I not getting a compiler error here? 
//This arrow function does not properly implement EventHandler<T>
})
```

Comment: Why do you think these types are not propertly implemented? Do you mean that it doesn't accept an argument? Javascript is not java, here if function accepts no arguments, you can still call it with some and it will not be a runtime error. So you are free to omit arguments that you don't use. See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters-in-callbacks) in TS docs

Comment: To add to @AlexChashin's comment, if the observe function would not be compatible (e.g. it would take params of different type), that would be an error.
This way it just explicitly leaves out "unused" parameters (AFAIK some lint configs even suggest to do that), but the typehint on `model.observe` is the original full type (which is good IMHO) regardless of implementation.